# How to minimize your jQuery plug-in

Tags: jquery-plugins, compression, minimize

I've wrote a `jQuery plug-in` and i would like to `minimize` it but I don't know how to do it correctly, does exists some tool to do it or should I do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) or [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)

Hope this helps

Comment: Add in the Google Closure Compiler (http://code.google.com/closure/compiler) and you've covered the main three.  Uglify can be finicky to get working, but seems to be the best in terms of speed, compression and stability, while the other two are java based so dead simple to get up and running but are somewhat slower.  The closure compiler also has many other potentially useful features for large applications.